# I am getting python2 failed errors on npm install

Tags: python, node.js, powershell, npm

I am getting errors when running npm install in windows powershell, I need to be using node version 8.11.1 so I am using nvm to do so. I tried downgrading to python 2.7 but that didn't work so I upgraded back to python 3.7 still didn't work. Here is my outputted error, any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the project I am trying to run https://github.com/jadnco/static-boilerplate

I have also tried deleting my node modules each time, a package-lock.json is never even generated so i didn't delete that.

```
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@0.4.0: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js

> node-sass@3.13.1 install C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-64_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/win32-x64-64_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.13.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python37\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\andersk\\sites\\forkable-email-template\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\andersk\sites\forkable-email-template\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\andersk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-18T22_17_30_755Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 28):

So running this command worked

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

I thought I had tried that already but I guess I needed to do it in powershell administrative mode

Comment: why all of sudden is this needed? I never had to use windows-build-tools before today for npm projects in Windows.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue but I'm on Ubuntu (Linux). What should I do?

Comment: Any suggestion on how to use it with jfrog(node modules) on windows server?

Comment: This command just hangs for me on Windows 10.

Comment: hangs for me too

Comment: On linux helped me: `apt-get install python`

Comment: What if I'm on macOS??

Comment: [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765407/for-npm-dependencies-powershell-is-stuck-after-installing-vs-build-tools-and-it) thread and [this github](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/172) issue offer some solutions on how to fix the hanging issue on windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing GetText from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm.
Make sure you add `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` to the PATH