# For npm dependencies, PowerShell is stuck after installing VS Build tools and it says it is still waiting for installer log file to install python?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm-install

The command I used (run as administrator):

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with Powershell.

Comment: It is my first ever question on stack overflow so forgive me for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 39):

I also faced the same problem and I tried with the below command, it worked.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```

Regards,
venkatesh.

Comment: I attempted to edit, but edits must be at least 6 characters. This answer is incorrect by one character. `windows-build-tool` should be `windows-build-tools`

Comment: @EricNemchik yeah, I fixed it with my higher reputation, thanks for your nice notice.

Comment: This hangs just the same for me. edit: (it worked nvm)

Answer (score 3):

I am running into the issue above. After google, I luckily find [a related thread on github](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/172#issuecomment-824916268) about how to resolve stuck when installing `windows-build-tool` with npm from powershell on Windows. The following are a bunch of screenshots.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Spot On!!

You can simply hit below command:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0
```

It will work for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue and solved it by following this guide:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to try installing the build tools via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) instead (use an Administrator command line):

```
choco install python visualstudio2017-workload-vctools -y
```

Credits to [karlhorky](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/240#issuecomment-824916057)

Answer (score 0):

**OS: Windows 11 Pro**

**Tried these, but any of them didn't work for me:**

- `npm install --global windows-build-tools`
- `npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0`
- `npm install --global windows-build-tools@5.0.0`
- `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
- `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0`
- `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@5.0.0`
- `npm config set msvs_version 2015 global`
- `npm config set msvs_version 2017 global`

**Then Install Chocolatey**
https://chocolatey.org/install

Followd this resource:
https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/172#issuecomment-824916268

```
$ choco install python visualstudio2017-workload-vctools -y
$ npm config set msvs_version 2017
```

Got this error when run `$ npm i`

```
Error: 'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,   operable program or batch file.
```

**Solution:**

```
$ choco uninstall cmake
$ choco install cmake --installargs 'ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=System'
```

Now I don't get any errors when run `$ npm i`